# How to add Speech Recognition to website in input tag?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I want to know how I can add the speech recognition to any input tag in Website.
I have gone through many tutorials on web and all the sites on which even demo is not showing that microphone icon.
I have even read the documentation [Api Description](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-xg-htmlspeech/2011Feb/att-0020/api-draft.html). Please suggest what is creating problem or google has disabled it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is the way You can add speech recognition in your website with  html5  tag attribute 
**x-webkit-speech** .
The code you need to add in your website look like below .

```
<p id="msg">
</p>
<div id="speech-input">
    Enter input ::<input type="text" id="text" x-webkit-speech>
</div>
```

This input attributes will not supported by most of the web browsers.So you can check whether your site support this or not using below js

```
var msg = document.getElementById('msg');

if (document.createElement('input').webkitSpeech === undefined) {
msg.innerHTML = "x-webkit-speech is <strong>not supported</strong> in your browser.";
} else {
msg.innerHTML = "x-webkit-speech is <strong>supported</strong> in your browser.";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ajesh, but it`s not working on my side. Like I have mentioned above that I have checked many tutorials. Please confirm if above code is working on your side or you can provide me live example.